# A Nine Letter Word

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking, rhyme

Once upon a time, there was a young prince. This prince had a puzzle instructor, and one day he arrived in his instructor's chambers, only to find that there was only a note on his table.

> *I've left you this riddle, dear prince, you see,*
>   *This is a test, while I rest my knee.*
>   *There are plenty of reasons to find it absurd,*
>   *But the key comes in the form of a nine letter word.*

Now, the young prince had been given tests like this before, and knew that he was simply to write his solution on the back of the note. He pondered it for a minute, then turned over the note and wrote down his answer, certain it was right.

***What did the prince give as his solution?***

Comment: Did he write his solution on the front of the note?

Comment: @Goldname No, I just didn't feel that specifying that was necessary :P I edited to clarify

Comment: Uucaira...  Two missing.

Comment: @Mithrandir If you include numbers, you get UUCAIR2A9, which is 9 characters. I don't know if it means anything or if it's even on the right track.

Comment: @MikeQ wrong track according to the op in chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP pressured me to post this:

> A nine letter word.

Since it said that it was in the form of a nine letter word.

Comment: Accepted? Huh???

Comment: Um, the *form* of a 9-lettered word is **not equal to** a nine lettered word

Comment: @Sid but `a nine-letter word` is in 'the form of **a nine letter word**'.

Comment: I need someone to explain this to my like im 5 please

Comment: @AnthonyFornito Okay. The words *A nine-letter word* are **located in the phrase** 'But the key comes in the form of **a nine letter word**.'. That clear?

Comment: I get that, keep in mind it the end of the day, and i read your last comment at least 20 times, I see the words 'A nine-letter word' and i see where that are located, I just dont see how that is the answer, I will let it settle in my brain over night probably plam -> forehead tomorrow

Comment: @AnthonyFornito the key word is **in**. It's **in** that phrase.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution, the prince writes the word

> I

because

> "I" is the ninth letter of the alphabet, and is also a word. From a certain perspective, it could be called a "nine letter" word for this reason. This may seem absurd because the phrase "nine letter word" suggests that the word contains nine letters.